# Belkin USB-C LAN not functioning on MacOS

Tags: network, usb

I have a 2018 Macbook pro with MacOS 10.13.6. 
To have a more stable connection (compared to WiFi) I got a "Belkin USB-C to Ethernet Adapter". 
Initially, the adapter had a self-assigned IP which I fixed by changing how the IPv4 in Network settings is configured from `DHCP` to `DHCP with manual address`. Now the status is green and the device is assigned an IP address. However, there is still no connectivity through this device. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't trick your ethernet to start working by just changing the IP address. If the Ethernet adapter doesn't get an address from the DHCP server the first place to look at is the router.

Comment: I am not sure if I am opening myself for a hack here, but I have not limited the addresses at the router.

Comment: It's not about address limitations as such, but if the Mac doesn't get an IP address from the DHCP server within the router over Ethernet this indicates faulty cables or configuration issues on the side of the router. Check the answers on the linked question for details and ways to analyze the problem.